# Computing the derived $I$ invariants $D(G\operatorname{Rep})\to D((G/I)\operatorname{Rep})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, group-cohomology, derived-categories

In Scholze's paper [The Langlands–Kottwitz approach for the modular curve](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1935) ([published version](https://doi.org/10.1093/imrn/rnq225)) about $\operatorname{GL}_2$ when he wants to find the relation between the semisimple trace and the usual trace he claims that if $I = I_K\subset G_K$ is the inertia group of a local number field $K$ with residue field $k$ and $V$ is a representation of $G_k$ such that $I_k$ acts through a finite cyclic quotient then $R_I(V)$, $R_{I}:D(\operatorname{Rep}_{\overline{\mathbb Q_l}}(G_K))\to D(\operatorname{Rep}_{\overline{\mathbb Q_l}}(G_k))$  is represented by $$\dotsb\to 0\to V^I\to V^I(1)\to \ 0 \to\dotsb.$$

I think essentially we can reduce the problem to $\mathbb F_l$ coefficients and we can assume $I=\langle s\rangle$ is a finite cyclic group and $G_K=I\rtimes 
\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ but I can't compute the derived functor in this case. I think that if $w:D(\operatorname{Rep}_{\mathbb F_l}(\hat{\mathbb{Z}}))\to D(\mathbb F_l)$ is the forgetful functor then $R_I\circ w$ is represented by $$0\to V[I]\xrightarrow{s-1} V[I]
\xrightarrow{N}V[I]\to \dotsb$$
but then $R_I$ can't be represented by the complex in the first paragraph.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By "Scholze's paper about $\operatorname{GL}_2$" do you mean [Scholze - The local Langlands correspondence for $\operatorname{GL}_n$ over $p$-adic fields](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-012-0420-5)?

Comment: No I mean "the langlands kottwitz method for the modular curve"

Comment: [OK](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368016/computing-the-derived-i-invariants-dg-operatornamerep-to-dg-i-operator#comment928296_368016), I have edited in the link.